# Avoid sorting the json response data alphabetically on ajax call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, sorting

I am creating a utility that reads the data present in the table and on clicking the download button the data from the table should get exported to a csv file.

Currently, the order of data getting from the server side is as expected. However, in the console on the client side, the data gets sorted in alphabetical order automatically. And hence the data downloaded in csv is also not in the expected order.

For eg. I have below data in table which I am reading in the given order itself:

#### Table Employee

| Sr.No | EmployeeID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | Abc |

On clicking the download button, I see below order in the browser's console

```js
{
  EmployeeID:12345,
  Name:Abc,
  Sr.No:1
}
```

And hence data in csv file downloaded looks as below

```
EmployeeID,Name,Sr.No
12345,Abc,1
```

I don't want this sorted order instead it should be as below

```
Sr.No,EmployeeId,Name
1,12345,Abc
```

function json2csv(objArray){

```
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
         

        line += array[i][index] + ',';
    }
        line = line.slice(0,-1)
    str += line + '\r\n';
}

return str;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really sorting, since there's only one record; it's ordering of properties. What are you using to convert from the object to the CSV file? That should have an option to order how you want it.

Comment: Here for example, i have shown only one record. There are 100+ records in the table. I am using a javascript to convert the json into csv. I have used the below code.                         function json2(objArray)   {var array=

Comment: can't you make the output code render the order?? Where is the code that generates the CSV? Object's order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Code added in main question

Comment: @epascarello could you please suggest how to render the order in the above code

Answer (score 1):

I would store the order of the CSV columns you want, I would loop over that to generate the CSV data from the object and not rely on object key order.

```js
var data = [{
  EmployeeID: 12345,
  Name: "ABC",
  "Sr.No": 1
}, {
  EmployeeID: 6789,
  Name: "CDE",
  "Sr.No": 2
}];

var csvOrder = ['Sr.No', 'EmployeeID', 'Name'];

function processCSV(columns, data) {
  var header = csvOrder.join(",");
  var rows = data.map(function (row) {
    const rowData = csvOrder.map(function (key){ return row[key]; });
    return rowData.join(",");
  });

  rows.unshift(header);
  return rows.join("\n\r");
}

console.log(processCSV(csvOrder, data));
```